# Modeling Favorites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking to add a `Favorite` model to my `User` and `Link` models.

**Business Logic**

- Users can have multiple links (that is, they can add multiple links)
- Users can favorite multiple links (of their own or other users)
- A Link can be favorited by multiple users but have one owner

I'm confused as to how to model this association and how would a user favorite be created once the models are in place?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :links
  has_many :favorites
end

class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  #can be favorited by multiple users 
end

class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :link 
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about the following data model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :links
  has_many :favorites, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :favorite_links, :through => :favorites, :source => :link
end

class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :favorites, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many   :favorited, :through => :favorites, :source => :user
end

class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :link
end
```

Since `User` already has an association called `links`, and `Link` already has one called `users`, we cannot use the same name for the `has_many :through` association (e.g. `User has_many :links, :through => :favorites` would not work). So, we invent a new association name, and help Rails know what association to load from the intermediary association via the `source` attribute.

Here's some pseudocode for using this association:

```
# Some users
user1 = User.create :name => "User1"
user2 = User.create :name => "User2"

# They create some links
link1_1 = user1.links.create :url => "http://link1_1"
link1_2 = user1.links.create :url => "http://link1_2"
link2_1 = user2.links.create :url => "http://link2_1"
link2_2 = user2.links.create :url => "http://link2_2"

# User1 favorites User2's first link
user1.favorites.create :link => link2_1
# User2 favorites both of User1's links
user2.favorites.create :link => link1_1
user2.favorites.create :link => link1_2

user1.links          => [link1_1, link1_2]
user1.favorite_links => [link2_1]
user2.links          => [link2_1, link2_2]
user2.favorite_links => [link1_1, link1_2]
link1_1.favorited    => [user2]

link2_1.destroy

user1.favorite_links => []
user2.links          => [link2_2]
```

Comment: Would I need to create `Favorite_Link` and `Favorited` models?

Comment: No; the `has_many :through` combined with the `class_name` options indicates that Rails should look into the given association for another association in there, essentially jumping through two models to get the right objects.

Comment: DISREGARD [Explained above]: Thanks, I'm having trouble understanding how we can reference :favorited and :favorite_links in models without those existing as models themselves. Is there a name for this technique? I would like to read up on it to understand how it works.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try. Thanks for the thorough explanations and pseudocode

Comment: By default, Rails tries to infer the model name based on the association; we're telling Rails through the `class_name` option in the association to use that model. Rails infers the foreign key in the other table based on the name of the model the association is defined in, so no extra configuration is necessary.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to give it a shot. I really appreciate your help, this will get me going

Comment: With apologies, I forgot one more attribute, `source`, which tells rails which key to look on for a `has_many :through`, and thus we don't need the `class_name` attribute. Check the updated answer once more!

Comment: Thanks, I'm implementing the code now. Could you explain the difference between :favorites and :favorite_links in the user model. In reviewing the pseudocode, I noticed that one is used for creating favorites and the other for displaying favorites. Could I group these?

Comment: If you did a `user.favorite_links.create`, this would try to create a `Link` and then associate it with `user`'s favorites. You probably only want to create instances of `Favorite` and assign them to links that already exist. Remember that in a traditional model this would be `user.links` instead of `user.favorite_links`, and `user.links.create` would create a new `Link` (and not a new `Favorite`). We only use the term `favorite_links` because `links` is already taken.

Comment: Said another way, you can think of the `has_many :favorite_links, :through => :favorites` as looking *through* the user's `Favorites` and into the `Links` that those favorites belong to. It's just a shortcut, essentially the same as `user.favorites.map { |f| f.link }` (but more efficient)